# How can I reshape a column of words into a single line using vim?

Tags: vim

I have a column of words:

```
text
text 
text
text
text
```

and I am searching for a vim command that will produce:

```
text text text text text
```

A macro will work of course, but is there something simpler for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just replace all newlines (\n or \r\n depending on your OS) with spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro would work, yes, but it's probably not the most efficient method.

How about a simple substitution:

```
:%s/\n/ <-- whitespace!
```

Or simply a "join":

```
5J
```

***edit***

Not knowing what your file looks like, it's difficult to propose a definitive answer. The substitution assumes that the buffer only contains the lines in your example (the `%` means "whole buffer") while the join assumes those lines are somehow located in a sea of text and uses an absolute count for more precision.

The `J` normal mode command, like its sister the `:join` Ex command, can work on a range/selection so it is entirely possible to select visually those lines and hit `J`:

```
V<down><down><down><down>J
v4jJ
5VJ
etc.
```

Comment: "join" did the trick, but I selected the lines in the visual mode using "V" and then simply pressed "J". It would be cool if you added this to your answer, I'll accept it anyway. :) Thanks!

Comment: Haha, I actually thought about adding this solution, but I didn't know the structure of your file so I went with a specific solution, `5J`.